# Chromedp working in non-headless but doing nothing in headless

Tags: go, chromedp

I am using Chromedp to post some stuff occasionally on Social Media. When I run the script in non-headless mode it is working perfect.

When I try to run it in headless mode, nothing happens. Obviously something is going wrong, but since I cannot "see" what is going wrong I am clueless.

Can anyone tell me how one should debug something when not able to visually see what Chromedp is doing?

And maybe explain to me why non-headless is working but headless not, because I do not understand how that can be.

I tried it with this code (minimized it), and in non-headless it works perfect. As soon as I go headless is doesn't do anything.

```
opts := append(chromedp.DefaultExecAllocatorOptions[:],
        chromedp.Flag("headless", false),
    )
    actx, acancel := chromedp.NewExecAllocator(context.Background(), opts...)
    defer acancel()

    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(
        actx,
        chromedp.WithLogf(log.Printf),
    )
    defer cancel()

    ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(ctx, 120*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    err = chromedp.Run(ctx,
        emulation.SetUserAgentOverride("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:101.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/101.0"),
        //chromedp.ResetViewport(),
        chromedp.Navigate("https://example.com/"),

        chromedp.Sleep(time.Second*5),
        chromedp.MouseClickXY(1075, 33),
        chromedp.Sleep(time.Second*5),
                // A LOT MORE CLICKS AND KEY PRESSES GOING ON
        chromedp.MouseClickXY(850, 61),
        chromedp.Sleep(time.Second*10),

        // end
        chromedp.Stop(),
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

I added a "debug" line and now I see tons and tons of code (HTML I guess) output in my console but I still cannot figure out where it goes wrong in all honesty.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me how one should debug something when not able to visually see what Chromedp is doing?

##### Enable the debug log

```golang
ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(
    actx,
    chromedp.WithDebugf(log.Printf),
)
```

The output will be quite a lot. Redirect the output to a file so that you can examine it carefully and share it to others if in need.

And read the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) to understand the log.

#### Take a screenshot

You can take a screenshot with one of the following funcs:

- [chromedp.CaptureScreenshot](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/chromedp/chromedp#CaptureScreenshot): take a screenshot of the current browser viewport.
- [chromedp.FullScreenshot](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/chromedp/chromedp#FullScreenshot): take a full screenshot of the entire page.

You can even [start a screencast](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-startScreencast) to save a series of images. See an example [here](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/1283).

---

> And maybe explain to me why non-headless is working but headless not

##### The viewport has a different size in headless mode

If the page is responsive and adapt to different window sizes, then `chromedp.MouseClickXY` with a hard-coded position could fail. Take a screenshot to confirm that. Avoid using `chromedp.MouseClickXY` directly. Use `chromedp.Click` to click a specific element.

If in need, you can use [chromedp.WindowSize](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/chromedp/chromedp#WindowSize) to set the initial size of the window. Or use [chromedp.EmulateViewport](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/chromedp/chromedp#EmulateViewport) to change the size of the viewport later.

##### The browser is detected as a bot

Another common reason is that the browser in headless mode is detected as a bot and the website refuses to serve the browser. See [Bot detection engines](https://developers.cloudflare.com/bots/plans/biz-and-ent/#bot-detection-engines).

To understand what it is, see some of the reported issues below:

- https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/1163
- https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/877
- https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/1069
- https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/1102

---

The issue is most likely caused by the usages of `chromedp.MouseClickXY` with hard-coded position. Since the question does not contain enough information, I can not do much about it. If you're stuck but can not share your use case publicly, you can send me an email with concrete information so that I can look into it.

Comment: Great answer! thank you so much. I will try out some of the things you said and will update my post accordingly!